# A Better Approximation at Lower Input Values

Tags: summation, algorithms, approximation

I'm doing some research on an algorithm and to give an upper bound I wanted to simplify the term, call it $T$, below.

\begin{equation} 
T(i)=\sum_{k=1}^{i-1}\sec\Big(\big(\frac{3}{4}\big)^{k-1}\big(45^{\circ}\big)\Big), 
\textrm{ for } i\geq 2\end{equation}

I've been able to come up with the approximation $T \leq i$, and this approximation is good enough after the first few values of $i$, but  the lower the value of $i$, the more accurate I need $T$ to be. Is there a more accurate approximation at lower values of $i$ for this?

Comment: Additional term as i increases tend to 1.  Does that help?  What lower values of i do you want?  The minimum is 2.

Comment: @herbsteinberg If I had to give an example then I would say $T \leq i$ is a good approximation for $i > 10$, but the lower the value of $i$, the more important that $T(i)$ be accurate

Comment: Noe that sec > 1 for each k in you series.  My only suggestion is try using the exponential representation $sec(x)=\frac{2}{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}$, although it might be clumsy.

Comment: The statement "$T\le i$" is a little confusing, since T is a function of i.

Comment: It's just saying that the output of the function, $T$, is less than the input of the function, $i$.

Comment: I came up with $T(i) \leq \Big(i-\big(\frac{89}{200}\big)^{i-1}-0.14\Big)$ by messing around with some numbers, I don't think I can get it much better than that

Comment: I have nothing more to add.  Have you tried plotting and using a least squares fit with a curve looking like what you have with the constants replaced by parameters to be determined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using that $\sec x<1+x^2/2$ you can get
$$
T(i)<i-1+\frac{\pi^2}{126}\Bigl(9-16\Bigl(\frac{9}{16}\Bigr)^i\Bigr)=i-0.709042-1.25328\Bigl(\frac{9}{16}\Bigr)^i.
$$
This can be improved using more terms in the Taylor series of $\sec x$ around $x=0$.